# what is dependencies, build, installing about apt ? (intalling xrandr-invert-colors)

Tags: 18.04, xcalib

I want to install `xrandr-invert-colors` on my ubuntu 18.04 to invert display of laptop and monitor both.
but have no idea what is dependencies, build and how to install it. 
Yeah~ I am ubuntu newbie and have typed only `sudo apt-get install 000` ).
Installing this package is the hardest job ever, for me~

description on the github as follow:

> Dependencies
>
> > XrandR development files (apt-get install libxcb-randr0-dev)
> >
> > Type sudo make deps-apt on Debian / Ubuntu
>
> Building
>
> > From a terminal, type make Installing
> >
> > Execute sudo make install after build to put the binary in the following location: /usr/local/bin/xrandr-invert-colors

Actuall, I have already typed `sudo apt-get install libxcb-randr0-dev`
but the next code `sudo make deps-apt` didn't work.

> make: *** No rule to make target 'deps-apt'.  Stop.

Comment: Avoid the deep end of the pool until you know how to swim a bit better, Compiling and makefiles require *understanding* of the concepts you are employing. Merely typing incantations into a terminal means you cannot fix it when it breaks...and it can break a lot of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors
So the actual steps are:

1. clone codes and enter root of code;

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors.git
   $ cd xrandr-invert-colors
   ```
2. install dependencies, actually it is doing "sudo apt-get install libxcb-randr0-dev";

   ```
   $ sudo make deps-apt
   ```
3. build the binary;

   ```
   $ make
   ```
4. install the binary;

   ```
   $ sudo make install
   ```
5. Now you can use "xrandr-invert-colors" which is installed as "/usr/local/bin/xrandr-invert-colors", as you can see on github page.

Answer (score 1):

xcalib is in the repository for 18.04 and will complete this task for you.

meaning that all you need to do is type

```
sudo apt-get install xcalib
```

You will be prompted to enter your password.
Then you will see the following output:

[image]

After `processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...`

You should be able to simply type `xcalib`, which will show both how to use the package, and that the package has installed successfully.

There is a guide on Xcalib for Ubuntu [here](https://brutusfacticus.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/how-to-invert-screen-colors-in-ubuntu-based-gnulinux-distros/) that might help you.